# Play Framework 2.5/2.6 and Form in scala.html template

Tags: playframework

i am learning Play Framework 2.6 and I would like to ask you how to properly use Form and access those data in my template. I am not very clever from the documentation.

in the Controller, I send this to the template:

```
Form<LoginForm> loginForm = formFactory.form(LoginForm.class).bindFromRequest();

if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
    return ok(userLoginForm.render(loginForm));
}
```

In the html scala template, after I do POST of the form to server, if I print @form, I get

```
@(form: Form[LoginForm])

content of @form=    
Form(of=class controllers.forms.LoginForm, data={Submit=Login, password=12, email=mail}, 
value=Optional[controllers.forms.LoginForm@53122070], 
errors=[ValidationError(email,[Please use email in proper format.],[]), ValidationError(password,[Password must be longer than 3 characters],[]), ValidationError(,[Please fix all errors.],[])])
```

Please how can I access these data from the template (using the @form...xyz....):

1. How to display the email value, in this case it will show "mail"
2. How to display the password value, in this case, it will show "12"
3. How to display the one Global error message (or the first one if there are more), its "Please fix all errors." in our case
4. How to display error message associated with the email
5. How to display error message associated with the password

Comment: Have you read the documentation on forms? It answers and has examples of each of your questions https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#toolbar

Comment: yes, for the Java part ... but I dont want to use <form> generated by them, I write them myself, so I dont know how to access those  data. I will try it over the weekend more.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out some of my questions.

To get the email value:

```
 @form.data.get("email")
```

To get the password value:

```
@form.data.get("password")
```

To get the one global error message:

```
@if(!form("").errors.isEmpty()) {
    @form("").errors.get(0).message()
}
```

(but I prefer to put the  global error into the flash())

To list all "email" error messages:

```
@for(error <- form("email").errors) {
    @error.message  
}
```

I know there might be more elegant solution, but this is what I have now.

Comment: in Play framework 2.6 , you can use @form.rawData.get("email")